# ResourceBundle lookup on message_de.properties and message_de_DE.properties

Tags: java

Some time our application looks for message_de.properties file where as sometimes it looks up for message_de_DE.properties.

We are storing the locale string in the Database where locale string value will be en_US en de ja

Did anyone come across the issue or have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the case that the messages from `_de` file are not existing in `_de_DE` file? My understanding is that the latter can override the former.

Comment: No. when we create a new file as _de with the same value it worked fine..would like to know when it looks for _de and when it looks for _de_DE

Comment: What is your `Locale`, and is this always consistent?